semilinear transport equation
Good morning everyone!
I have to solve the following transport equation for the temperature $T(x,t)$:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = k(T_a - T)
$$
with boundary conditions: $T(0,t) = T_e$ and $T(x,0) = T_0$.
Using the characteristic method I have found that the characteristic lines are $x = vt + x_0$ and the equation to found the solution is $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k(T_a-T)$
we get $-ln|T_a-T| = kt + C$, where C is the integration constant, giving us $T = T_a + e^{ -kt + C}$ than can be rewritten as
$T = T_a + Ae^{ -kt}$
Forcing the initial condition for the time -> $T(x,0) = T_0 = T_a + A$ we get $A = T_0-T_a$
So the final solution should be $T(x,t) = T_a + (T_0-T_a)e^{kt}$.
Now comes the questions: is this solution correct? I found it without enforcing one of the starting conditions. Moreover, it looks like it depends only on $t$, while I'd like to see also the dependence on $x$ somehow.
Any idea or opinions?
Thank you all!

Since your characteristic curves are lines, imagine picking a point in the first quadrant of the $(x,t)$ plane and tracing the characteristic curve "backwards". Then for some points, this line will cross the $t$-axis axis first and thus be described by the $T(0,t)$ condition. But others will cross the $x$-axis first and thus be described by the $T(x,0)$ condition.

ohhh I see it now, so for $x<=vt$ we use the time condition $T_0$ while for $x>vt$ we use the space condition $T_e$. Thank you!

Correct, though I wouldn't say $x\leq vt$ for the first case: the two boundary conditions are incompatible at $(0,0)$, so there's no particular reason to pick one in favor of the other. Hence the case $x=vt$ is simply not well-defined.

Correct is
$$T! \left(x,t\right)=T_{a}+\left(T_{0}-T_{a}\right) {\mathrm e}^{\color{red}-k t}$$

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = k(T_a - T)
$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{v}=\frac{dT}{k(T_a-T)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{v}$ :
$$x-vt=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dT}{k(T_a-T)}$ :
$$(T_a-T)e^{kt}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$(T_a-T)e^{kt}=F(x-vt)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the boundary and initial conditions).
$$\boxed{T(x,t)=T_a-e^{-kt}F(x-vt)}$$
CONDITIONS: $T(0,t) = T_e$ and $T(x,0) = T_0$
One observe that $T(0,0)=T_e=T_a$. In the general case $T_e\neq T_a$. This implies that the above function $F$ is a piecewise function.
Initial condition :
$T(x,0) = T_0=T_a-e^{-0}F(x-0)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=T_a-T_0$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution :
$$T(x,t)=T_a-e^{-kt}(T_a-T_0) \tag 1$$
Boundary condition :
$T(0,t) = T_e=T_a-e^{-kt}F(0-vt)$
Let $X=-vt\quad\implies\quad t=-\frac{X}{v}\quad\implies\quad T_e=T_a-e^{\frac{k}{v}X}F(X) \quad\implies\quad F(X)=(T_a-T_e)e^{-\frac{k}{v}X}$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x-vt$ :
$$T(x,t)=T_a-e^{-kt}(T_a-T_e)e^{-\frac{k}{v}(x-vt)}$$
$$T(x,t)=T_a-(T_a-T_e)e^{-\frac{k}{v}x} \tag 2$$
The whole function $T(x,t)$ is a picewise function made of the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$. They are several cases and possible domains depending on the relative values of $T_a$ , $T_0$ , $T_e$.
